# Loading an MVC JS bundle externally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I have a small JS library in my MVC 5 project that I want to be available for external users to load into their apps.  At the moment I'm bundling it like so:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/clientApi")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Api/clientapps/", "*.js"));
```

I can then access the bundled library via  browser at the path `/clientApi`.

However, it's always minified, even though I've set my web.config debug=true, and other bundles in my own app are included as non-minified.

How can I make the file/s in the bundle available as a non-minified bundle file?

Comment: If you do not want to minify it then why process it through the bundler?

Comment: Yep. Just link to the normal un-minified file. It's like HTML 101.

Comment: I want to minify it when I set the web.config debug=false attribute.  If it's set to true, I don't want it minified.  I don't want to have to change the path to the bundle to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access `/clientApi` directly then yes it will be the bundled/minified version.

The `debug=true` option effects *your* script reference in *your own* `.cshtml` file. When `debug=true`, references to the individual script files are rendered to the client (so the client doesn't use `/clientApi` at all).

When `debug=false`, then a reference to `/clientApi` (with the version query string) is rendered to the client instead, so they get the bundled/minified version... If you give that link to these external users, then that is what is going to get rendered.

That path doesn't care if it is debug or not. It's not like `/clientApi` is going to bundle but not minify the files depending on your compilation settings... it's just either *your app* is going to render the bundled/minified path or the individual script paths.

If you want to do debugging/testing in external apps, then they will just have to use the individual script paths.

Even if you do give these external apps the `/clientApi` reference once testing is done and they are ready to use the bundled/minified version, it doesn't explain how you are going to handle versioning. If you update a script, how will they know to stop caching?

Comment: Thanks, pretty much covers all the small points I was hoping/wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can serve the bundle unminified if you disable the transforms of the Bundles

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; // Force bundling to occur

    // If the compilation node in web.config indicates debugging mode is enabled
    // then clear all transforms. I.e. disable Js and CSS minification.
    if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) {
        BundleTable.Bundles.ToList().ForEach(b => b.Transforms.Clear());
    }
}
```